# Confused with jQuery UI Autocomplete function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement jQuery UI Autocomplete behaviour in a Text Box.I have followed an example and It works fine. But some syntax making me confused. Here is the code snippet:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.name, new { data_autocomplete_url = Url.Action("Autocomplete") })
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-autocomplete-url]')
        .each(function () {
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: $(this).data("autocomplete-url")
            });
        });
    });


</script>
```

I am declaring the TextBox to have an attribute `data-autocomplete-url`. But in the jQuery UI autocomplete function I am using only `autocomplete-url` without `data-` prefix. How this works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method already knows that you are calling the value of `data-*` attribute.
And does not require preceding `data-` before the name of attribute when calling it.